# Azure Active Directory - Update User - The request is currently not supported on the targeted entity set

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, active-directory, .net-core, azure-active-directory

We're developing micro-services based architecture solution with Azure AD and other Azure PaaS services.

The good thing is, that we were able to use Microsoft.Graph SDK for .NET Core 2.1 and we were able to do authentication and to create users in Azure AD.

The problem is that we're unable to update user profile. GraphServiceClient provides us with a way of updating user, however we're receiving **BadRequest** with error message **The request is currently not supported on the targeted entity set**.

I also tried Graph Explorer online and I noticed, that Update User isn't there. How can we then incorporate profile updates?

Thank you very much.

```
// you have user object from AD and now you want to set some fields to update
user.Birthday = request.DateOfBirth;
user.PostalCode = request.Zip;

user = await _graphClient.Users[user.Id].Request().UpdateAsync(user);
// _graphClient is a GraphServiceClient instance
```

Comment: Could you add the code you are using?

Comment: Hi Juunas, do you have any idea what might be wrong?

Comment: I also read some known issues for Microsoft Graph, I didnt see any point about updating user, however they have still a lot of things missing there from AD Graph Api.

Comment: Hmm.. Seems like a problem with the SDK or the way you are using it. The Graph API allows a partial update with PATCH, but I am not sure what the SDK does.

Comment: We had a meeting with Microsoft guys, they explained a pretty straightforward way.. Graph API will not allow you to do the updates on Azure AD, you need to set up Azure AD B2C tenant.

Comment: That sounds.. a bit weird honestly. Considering I've built an app for the express purpose of modifying user data via MS Graph API.

Comment: Believe me, we were looking at each other and decided to go with Identity framework and SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code kind of matches their [example here](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/aspnet-snippets-sample/blob/master/Graph-ASPNET-46-Snippets/Microsoft%20Graph%20ASPNET%20Snippets/Models/UsersService.cs#L257), with the exception that you have set `user.Id`. Maybe it's trying to update the `Id` and that's why it's throwing the error. Try not setting `user.Id` and use a different variable to store the ID that you pass to `Users[]`.

Comment: I incorporated your suggestions
user = await _graphClient.Users[user.Id].Request().UpdateAsync(new User
                    {
                        Birthday = request.DateOfBirth,
                        PostalCode = request.Zip
                    });

however, the result is same. Message: The request is currently not supported on the targeted entity set

Comment: Oh well, it was worth a try. I don't have much experience with the Graph API yet, although I need to learn since our organization is moving to Office 365.

Comment: @TomasBlanárik Your issue most likely is related to this line `user.Birthday = request.DateOfBirth;` of your code. [See also](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57481004/1232087)